# How can I use Jquery's removeClass on an element that is ajax'd in?

Tags: jquery, ajax, removeclass

I am simply trying to use Jquery's removeClass() on an element that is pulled in via Ajax. I am well aware of being able to use .live() for actions like 'click', but what can I do for functions like removeClass()?

Note: I have heard of JQuery plugins that can do this, but I would rather simply program it myself using Jquery if it's not brutal.

Thanks,

Daniel Moniz

Edit: Sorry for the lack of information. I'm working on building an autocomplete tool. The user presses a key and gets a list of items pulled in via AJAX. The first item is automatically highlighted because (in the AJAX callback) I use .addClass() to give it the class 'highlight'.

If the user hits the up or down arrow key, however, they should be able to 'navigate' through the list, ie. I highlight (and un-highlight) items in the list. These actions are on button press, and the list has already been pulled in via AJAX. Therefore I can't remove the class in an Ajax callback.

`$(".highlight")` will effectively grab the currently highlighted element.

```
highlightedTopic.removeClass("highlight")
```

After performing the above code and then using `console.log($(".highlight"));`, I get an output of the element *with* the 'highlight' class. So the removeClass() function is failing (without error).

Comment: You can use it in the callback method. Can you provide more info, like your html and any javascript?

Comment: You need to explain much more. It's not clear at all what the problem is in the first place. `removeClass()` works on elements created through an AJAX request just like it does on original DOM elements. So you need to explain your specific case so that we can understand why it isn't working.

Comment: I've added some information above to clarify my situation.

Comment: The removeClass function isn't failing without error, you must be doing something wrong in terms of when you are trying to remove the class.  Without seeing your code it's hard to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assume all item  in list have class "listItem" and first item also has "highlight" class
   some thing like 
    
     text
     text
     text

then in your JS try this

```
$(".highlight").live("keyup",function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==38)//up key 
  {
   $(this).removeClass("highlight");
   $(this).prev(".listItem").addClass("highlight");
   }
  else if(e.keyCode==40)//down key
  {
   $(this).removeClass("highlight");
   $(this).next(".listItem").addClass("highlight");

   } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know why I didn't try this.

Answer (score 2):

Fire the `removeClass` in a success callback on the AJAX loader. It would be easier to demonstrate if you posted your code, but for example:

```
$("some element").load("someurl", function () { $("#awsmsauce").removeClass("satin shoes"); });
```

Comment: I am unable to put it in an AJAX loader, as the elements are already pulled into the page before I want to fire removeClass(). Please check out my edits.

Comment: @Paragon I don't think I need to edit the above. You can just use the success callback to attach event handlers to the parts of the page that will add and remove classes. There's no point in attaching the event handler until the list exists.

Comment: Thanks, kojiro! I'll be messing around with the bind function tonight.